# Produce elements with different data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a code which will allow me to show 8 pins on the map with different data (location, images, alt text, etc.), but when I run the code I get 8 pins with the exact same data. What am I doing wrong? As far as I am concerned, the getRandomInt function should produce various data, and since it's then used in the for loop, the data should be different each time. But I suppose I don't understand something correctly so if you can, please help me.

Thanks in advance!

```js
'use strict';
var TYPES = ['palace', 'flat', 'house', 'bungalo'];
var map = document.querySelector('.map');
var mapOverlay = document.querySelector('.map__overlay');
var pins = document.querySelector('.map__pins');
var ADS_COUNT = 8;

var getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

var similarAds = {
  'author': {
    'avatar': 'img/avatars/user0' + getRandomInt(1, ADS_COUNT) + '.png',
  },
  'offer': {
    'type': TYPES[getRandomInt(0, TYPES.length - 1)],
  },

  'location': {
    'x': getRandomInt(0, mapOverlay.offsetWidth),
    'y': getRandomInt(130, 630),
  }
};

var renderPin = function (pinData) {
  var element = document.createElement('button');
  var newImage = document.createElement('img');
  element.className = 'map__pin';
  element.style.top = pinData.location.y + 'px';
  element.style.left = pinData.location.x + 'px';
  newImage.src = pinData.author.avatar;
  newImage.alt = pinData.offer.type;
  element.appendChild(newImage);
  return element;
};

var renderPins = function () {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < ADS_COUNT; i++) {
    fragment.appendChild(renderPin(similarAds));
  }
  pins.appendChild(fragment);
};

map.classList.remove('map--faded');
renderPins();
```

```css
/* Общие стили. Каркас
   ========================================================================== */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Roboto-Bold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Medium.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Roboto-Medium.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-box-component {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;

  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;

  white-space: nowrap;

  -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);

          clip-path: inset(100%);
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  color: #353535;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;

  background-color: #f0f0ea;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border: 0;
}


/* Карта с объявлениями
   ========================================================================== */

.promo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50%;

  width: 211px;
  height: 45px;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;

  overflow: hidden;
  height: 750px;

  background-color: #82bcc0;
  background-image: url("../img/map.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;

  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.map__pins {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.map__overlay {
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;

  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.map__title {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 170px;

  font-size: 85px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.map--faded .map__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}


/**
 * Метка объявления
 */

.map__pin {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border: 0;
  background: none;
}

.map__pin:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px red);
          filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px red);
}

.map__pin img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

.map__pin:not(.map__pin--main)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  background-image: url("../img/pins.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -9px;
}

.map__pin:not(.map__pin--main):hover::after,
.map__pin:not(.map__pin--main):active::after,
.map__pin--active:not(.map__pin--main)::after {
  background-position: 0 -88px;
}

.map__pin:active img,
.map__pin--active img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 15px rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.7);
          box-shadow: 0 0 15px 15px rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.7);
}

.map__pin--main {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;

  cursor: move;
}

.map__pin--main img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  padding: 2px 6px 6px;

  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-7px);
          transform: translateY(-7px);

  border: solid 5px #ff5635;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

.map__pin--main:active img,
.map__pin--main--active img {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.map__pin--main svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -50px;
  left: -47px;

  width: 156px;
  height: 156px;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) scale(0);
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) scale(0);
          transform: rotate(120deg) scale(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 78px 78px;
      -ms-transform-origin: 78px 78px;
          transform-origin: 78px 78px;
}

.map__pin--main:hover ellipse {
  fill: rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.9);
}

.map__pin--main::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  content: "";

  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-top: solid 18px #fff;
  border-bottom: 0;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -6px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -6px);
          transform: translate(-50%, -6px);

  border-top-width: 22px;
  border-top-color: #ff5635;
}

.map--faded .map__pin--main svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(1);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(1);
          transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(1);
}

.map--faded .map__pin--main::after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
          transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
}

.map__pin--main text {
  font-size: 7px;
  font-weight: 700;

  fill: #ffffff;
}


/**
 * Фильтры объявления
 */

.map__filters-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(3, 28, 45, 0.5);
}

.map__filters {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;

  width: 960px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;

  opacity: 1;
}

.map--faded .map__filters {
  opacity: 0;
}

.map__filter {
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;

  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.map__filter:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ffaa99;
}

.map__filter:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
          box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
}

.map__feature {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  width: 30px;
  height: 28px;

  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;

  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-image: url("../img/sprite-feature.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 345px;

  border-radius: 3px;
}

.map__feature--wifi {
  background-position: 2px 5px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--wifi {
  background-position: 2px -172px;
}

.map__feature--dishwasher {
  background-position: 2px -25px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--dishwasher {
  background-position: 2px -202px;
}

.map__feature--parking {
  background-position: 3px -55px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--parking {
  background-position: 2px -232px;
}

.map__feature--washer {
  background-position: 2px -85px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--washer {
  background-position: 2px -262px;
}

.map__feature--elevator {
  background-position: 2px -143px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--elevator {
  background-position: 2px -321px;
}

.map__feature--conditioner {
  background-position: 3px -114px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--conditioner {
  background-position: 2px -291px;
}

.map__feature:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffaa99;
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffaa99;
}

.map__feature:focus,
.map__checkbox:focus + .map__feature {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
           box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
 }

.map__feature:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #ff6547;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature {
  background-color: #ff6547;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}


/**
 * Карточка объявления
 */

.map__card {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 150px;
  left: 20px;

  padding: 10px 10px 20px;
  width: 230px;

  font-size: 12px;

  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.popup__avatar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;

  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;

  padding: 0;

  font-size: 0;

  border: 0;
  background: none;
}

.popup__close:active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
      -ms-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
          transform: translate(1px, 1px);
}

.popup__close:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #ff6547;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #ff6547;
}

.popup__close::after {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;

  display: block;
  content: "×";

  color: #000000;
}

.popup__title {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.popup__text {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__text--price {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.popup__price span {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.popup__type {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.popup__text--capacity {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.popup__features {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.popup__features {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__feature {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  width: 30px;
  height: 28px;

  font-size: 0;

  background-image: url("../img/sprite-feature.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 345px;
}

.popup__feature--wifi {
  background-position: 2px 5px;
}

.popup__feature--dishwasher {
  background-position: 2px -25px;
}

.popup__feature--parking {
  background-position: 3px -55px;
}

.popup__feature--washer {
  background-position: 2px -85px;
}

.popup__feature--elevator {
  background-position: 2px -143px;
}

.popup__feature--conditioner {
  background-position: 3px -114px;
}

.popup__photos {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.popup__photo {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.popup__photo:hover {
  border: 2px solid #ff5635;
}


/**
 * Сообщения об успешном и неуспешном создании объявления
 */

.success,
.error {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;

  padding-top: 300px;

  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.success__message,
.error__message {
  position: relative;

  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Кексобукинг</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="promo">
      <h1 class="promo__title visually-hidden">Keksobooking. Кексы по соседству</h1>
      <img src="img/keksobooking.svg" alt="Keksobooking. Кексы по соседству" width="215" height="45">
    </div>

    <!-- Карта объявлений -->
    <section class="map map--faded">

      <!-- Метки объявлений -->
      <div class="map__pins">
        <div class="map__overlay">
          <h2 class="map__title">И снова Токио!</h2>
        </div>
        <button class="map__pin map__pin--main" style="left: 570px; top: 375px;">
          <img src="img/muffin-red.svg" width="40" height="44" draggable="false" alt="Метка объявления">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 70 70" width="156" height="156" aria-label="Метка для поиска жилья">
            <defs>
              <path d="M35,35m-23,0a23,23 0 1,1 46,0a23,23 0 1,1 -46,0" id="tophalf" />
            </defs>
            <ellipse cx="35" cy="35" rx="35" ry="35" fill="rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.7)" />
            <text><textPath xlink:href="#tophalf" startOffset="0">Поставь меня куда-нибудь</textPath></text>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your variable similarAds. You have already defined it once and use the same value in your loop. So the simple way is to put your variable into the loop to redefined it with every new step.

```js
'use strict';
var TYPES = ['palace', 'flat', 'house', 'bungalo'];
var map = document.querySelector('.map');
var mapOverlay = document.querySelector('.map__overlay');
var pins = document.querySelector('.map__pins');
var ADS_COUNT = 8;

var getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

var renderPin = function (pinData) {
  var element = document.createElement('button');
  var newImage = document.createElement('img');
  element.className = 'map__pin';
  element.style.top = pinData.location.y + 'px';
  element.style.left = pinData.location.x + 'px';
  newImage.src = pinData.author.avatar;
  newImage.alt = pinData.offer.type;
  element.appendChild(newImage);
  return element;
};

var renderPins = function () {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var i = 0; i < ADS_COUNT; i++) {
  let similarAds = {
  'author': {
    'avatar': 'img/avatars/user0' + getRandomInt(1, ADS_COUNT) + '.png',
  },
  'offer': {
    'type': TYPES[getRandomInt(0, TYPES.length - 1)],
  },

  'location': {
    'x': getRandomInt(0, mapOverlay.offsetWidth),
    'y': getRandomInt(130, 630),
  }
};
    fragment.appendChild(renderPin(similarAds));
  }
  pins.appendChild(fragment);
};

map.classList.remove('map--faded');
renderPins();
```

```css
/* Общие стили. Каркас
   ========================================================================== */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Roboto-Bold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Medium.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Roboto-Medium.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-box-component {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;

  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;

  white-space: nowrap;

  -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);

          clip-path: inset(100%);
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  color: #353535;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;

  background-color: #f0f0ea;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border: 0;
}


/* Карта с объявлениями
   ========================================================================== */

.promo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50%;

  width: 211px;
  height: 45px;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;

  overflow: hidden;
  height: 750px;

  background-color: #82bcc0;
  background-image: url("../img/map.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;

  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.map__pins {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.map__overlay {
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;

  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.map__title {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 170px;

  font-size: 85px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.map--faded .map__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}


/**
 * Метка объявления
 */

.map__pin {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  border: 0;
  background: none;
}

.map__pin:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px red);
          filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px red);
}

.map__pin img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;

  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

.map__pin:not(.map__pin--main)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  background-image: url("../img/pins.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -9px;
}

.map__pin:not(.map__pin--main):hover::after,
.map__pin:not(.map__pin--main):active::after,
.map__pin--active:not(.map__pin--main)::after {
  background-position: 0 -88px;
}

.map__pin:active img,
.map__pin--active img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 15px rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.7);
          box-shadow: 0 0 15px 15px rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.7);
}

.map__pin--main {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;

  cursor: move;
}

.map__pin--main img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  padding: 2px 6px 6px;

  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-7px);
          transform: translateY(-7px);

  border: solid 5px #ff5635;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}

.map__pin--main:active img,
.map__pin--main--active img {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.map__pin--main svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -50px;
  left: -47px;

  width: 156px;
  height: 156px;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) scale(0);
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) scale(0);
          transform: rotate(120deg) scale(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 78px 78px;
      -ms-transform-origin: 78px 78px;
          transform-origin: 78px 78px;
}

.map__pin--main:hover ellipse {
  fill: rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.9);
}

.map__pin--main::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  content: "";

  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-top: solid 18px #fff;
  border-bottom: 0;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 300ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -6px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -6px);
          transform: translate(-50%, -6px);

  border-top-width: 22px;
  border-top-color: #ff5635;
}

.map--faded .map__pin--main svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(1);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(1);
          transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(1);
}

.map--faded .map__pin--main::after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
          transform: translate(-50%, -30px);
}

.map__pin--main text {
  font-size: 7px;
  font-weight: 700;

  fill: #ffffff;
}


/**
 * Фильтры объявления
 */

.map__filters-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(3, 28, 45, 0.5);
}

.map__filters {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;

  width: 960px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;

  opacity: 1;
}

.map--faded .map__filters {
  opacity: 0;
}

.map__filter {
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;

  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.map__filter:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ffaa99;
}

.map__filter:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
          box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
}

.map__feature {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  width: 30px;
  height: 28px;

  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;

  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-image: url("../img/sprite-feature.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 345px;

  border-radius: 3px;
}

.map__feature--wifi {
  background-position: 2px 5px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--wifi {
  background-position: 2px -172px;
}

.map__feature--dishwasher {
  background-position: 2px -25px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--dishwasher {
  background-position: 2px -202px;
}

.map__feature--parking {
  background-position: 3px -55px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--parking {
  background-position: 2px -232px;
}

.map__feature--washer {
  background-position: 2px -85px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--washer {
  background-position: 2px -262px;
}

.map__feature--elevator {
  background-position: 2px -143px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--elevator {
  background-position: 2px -321px;
}

.map__feature--conditioner {
  background-position: 3px -114px;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature--conditioner {
  background-position: 2px -291px;
}

.map__feature:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffaa99;
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffaa99;
}

.map__feature:focus,
.map__checkbox:focus + .map__feature {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
           box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ff6547;
 }

.map__feature:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #ff6547;
}

.map__checkbox:checked + .map__feature {
  background-color: #ff6547;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}


/**
 * Карточка объявления
 */

.map__card {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 150px;
  left: 20px;

  padding: 10px 10px 20px;
  width: 230px;

  font-size: 12px;

  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.popup__avatar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;

  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;

  padding: 0;

  font-size: 0;

  border: 0;
  background: none;
}

.popup__close:active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
      -ms-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
          transform: translate(1px, 1px);
}

.popup__close:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #ff6547;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #ff6547;
}

.popup__close::after {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;

  display: block;
  content: "×";

  color: #000000;
}

.popup__title {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.popup__text {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__text--price {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.popup__price span {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.popup__type {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.popup__text--capacity {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.popup__features {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.popup__features {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__feature {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  width: 30px;
  height: 28px;

  font-size: 0;

  background-image: url("../img/sprite-feature.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 345px;
}

.popup__feature--wifi {
  background-position: 2px 5px;
}

.popup__feature--dishwasher {
  background-position: 2px -25px;
}

.popup__feature--parking {
  background-position: 3px -55px;
}

.popup__feature--washer {
  background-position: 2px -85px;
}

.popup__feature--elevator {
  background-position: 2px -143px;
}

.popup__feature--conditioner {
  background-position: 3px -114px;
}

.popup__photos {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.popup__photo {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.popup__photo:hover {
  border: 2px solid #ff5635;
}


/**
 * Сообщения об успешном и неуспешном создании объявления
 */

.success,
.error {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;

  padding-top: 300px;

  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.success__message,
.error__message {
  position: relative;

  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Кексобукинг</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="promo">
      <h1 class="promo__title visually-hidden">Keksobooking. Кексы по соседству</h1>
      <img src="img/keksobooking.svg" alt="Keksobooking. Кексы по соседству" width="215" height="45">
    </div>

    <!-- Карта объявлений -->
    <section class="map map--faded">

      <!-- Метки объявлений -->
      <div class="map__pins">
        <div class="map__overlay">
          <h2 class="map__title">И снова Токио!</h2>
        </div>
        <button class="map__pin map__pin--main" style="left: 570px; top: 375px;">
          <img src="img/muffin-red.svg" width="40" height="44" draggable="false" alt="Метка объявления">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 70 70" width="156" height="156" aria-label="Метка для поиска жилья">
            <defs>
              <path d="M35,35m-23,0a23,23 0 1,1 46,0a23,23 0 1,1 -46,0" id="tophalf" />
            </defs>
            <ellipse cx="35" cy="35" rx="35" ry="35" fill="rgba(255, 86, 53, 0.7)" />
            <text><textPath xlink:href="#tophalf" startOffset="0">Поставь меня куда-нибудь</textPath></text>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
```